# Grails+mongoDB : Can't serialize Map<String, Enum>

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Im using an enum in my application called PublishedState. I could save it normally before I started refactoring for i18n support.

Here are the relevant parts of the Theme domain class:

```
class Theme {

     Map<String, String> name  //language locale to name

     Map<String,PublishedState> state   //country locale to state

...
}
```

Now following code doesn't work:

```
Theme theme = new Theme(
name: [en: 'english name'],
state: [en: PublishedState.DRAFT]
)
assert theme.validate()
theme.save()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.example.myapp.PublishedState
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:234)
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putMap(BasicBSONEncoder.java:274)
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:196)
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:140)
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:86)
at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:27)
at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:142)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:252)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:211)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession$1.doInDB(MongoSession.java:153)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:352)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession.flushPendingInserts(MongoSession.java:129)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.flush(AbstractSession.java:238)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession.flush(MongoSession.java:113)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.support.DatastorePersistenceContextInterceptor.flush(DatastorePersistenceContextInterceptor.java:90)
at Console$_run_closure3_closure6_closure8.doCall(Console.groovy:74)
at Console$_run_closure3_closure6.doCall(Console.groovy:73)
at Console$_run_closure3_closure6.doCall(Console.groovy)
```

I couldn't find anything about it, only about old bugs about saving lists and collection of enums, which were supposed to be solved already

I'm using Grails version: 2.2.0, and mongo plugin :mongodb:1.0.0.GA

Any Ideas?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: does it save if you do a toString on the enum?

Comment: i guess i could do it, but to you consider it to be an elegant solution? Without the Map, the mongo-plugin know to marshall and demarshall String the Enum and back... I wonder why it fails to do so when it's another data structure.

Comment: You can define a custom user type as well, but feels like making your life more complicated than it needs to be - http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html#3.6%20Custom%20User%20Types

Answer (score 0):

The BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField does NOT support Enums. A quick fix would be to do ourEnum.toString() or even better yourEnum.name() (since .name() gives the exact name of the Enum in a String and cannot be override).

Hope it helps.